# How to download all city page of my country from Wikipedia

Tags: download, wikipedia

Will it be moral to copy all city pages information for all cities in my country from Wikipedia?
I need those for my website.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia uses the [Creative Commons 3.0 Share and Share Alike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aText_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License) license which means that you *can* copy the content but it requires proper attribution.

You can read more information on their [Terms of Use](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use) page. (I won't quote it in detail as it could change). The key points are that:

- You must have attribution of where it came from.
- You must pass on the same rights to others who might want to copy *your* content.
- You must indicate where your text differs from theirs.

Comment: In the content of my pages I'll be referring to the content as "Wikipedia info...". Attribution is not at all any issue. But how do I find all those pages for each city? Say for New York. I'm thinking to write a perl script to do it. But I've heard that Wikipedia is smart enough to filter "artificial" page requests say from my bot.

Comment: @John - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/627594/59303) on Stack Overflow. It's a couple of years old but should be still relevant.

Comment: atleast data extraction part may of my interest. But now sure how I can use it to extract details for a city like New York from Wikipedia New York main page.

Comment: The "how" part of the question would be more appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

*[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) offers free copies of all available content to interested users. These databases can be used for mirroring, personal use, informal backups, or database queries (such as for Wikipedia:Maintenance). All text content is licensed under the GNU Free Documentation License (GFDL).*

If you need only English content, you can fetch the English Wikipedia MySQL dump.

You can also access any article programmatically, one at a time in XML or as an RSS Feed.

You can [scrape specific portions of a Wikipedia article using YQL & jQuery](http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/02/data-scraping-with-yql-and-jquery/)

[You can even collect multiple Wikipedia pages in a basket and convert them all to a single PDF document](http://www.labnol.org/internet/print-wikipedia-as-pdf/13475/) (just like an ebook) with just a few mouse clicks and offer this is a download.